# Babel 6: Too many arguments passed error

Tags: javascript, babeljs

When I try running my server that uses babel 6, I get the following error:

`Error: /path/to/myapp/server.js: t.Identifier:  Too many arguments passed. Received 3 but can receive no more than 1`

Here's what my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
  "scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "postinstall": "bash ./scripts/npm-post.sh",
  "test": "mocha test"
},
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-core": "^6.0.20",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.0.15",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.0.15",
    "react": "^0.14.2",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.2",
    "react-helmet": "^2.1.1",
    "react-router": "^1.0.0-rc3",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.15",
  }
}
```

Here's my `app.js`

```
require('babel-core/register')({
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    'react'
  ]
});
require('./server.js')
```

And `server.js`

```
console.log('hi')
```

`hi` is not printed to the console.

Answer (score 4):

I've solved the issue, it appears to be a bug in the v6.0.14 version of `babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx`, here:
https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v6.0.14/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/src/index.js#L36

the v6.0.14 version of the plugin is required by the latest version of the babel react preset
https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-react/package.json#L13

The latest version (v6.0.18) of `babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx` fixes the issue.
https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx/src/index.js#L36

So when I used the `react` preset, I got the above error.

To fix it, I changed my babel configuration to the following (note that I switched to using a `.babelrc` instead of an inline configuration in `app.js`, but the result should be the same.

`.babelrc` was:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

`.babelrc` is now:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

`package.json` now has the added dependency

```
"babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.0.18",
```

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by uninstalling the `babel-preset-react` plugin and then reininstalling so it installed the latest dependency. If that doens't work you may need to `rm -rf node_modules` and remove your `shrinkwrap` if you have one then rerun `npm install`